# Multiple monitors extended screen on all workspace

Tags: display, hardware

Plugged in an additional monitor

is it possible to have `extended screen` on all workspaces

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Do you want to extend the desktop to another monitor? If so, there's a setting inside system settings.

Comment: as of now only workspace gets extended to multiple monitors. Incase I switch workspaces, then is it possible to extend that workspace also onto the multiple monitors

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want (execute in terminal)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter workspaces-only-on-primary false
```

Works same as on gnome since it's based on gnome.

Comment: The workspace switcher though only shows on the primary monitor, so there's no way to switch to other workspaces without clicking on the dock application?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend your workspace on both monitors - System settings > Displays, disable Mirror Display and you can have extended workspace on both monitors. You can modify it by dragging both monitors top/bottom/left/right in order to fit how you want the space to be arranged.